# How to solve "node_modules/.bin/expo: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted" on Mac?

Tags: reactjs, terminal, dependencies, native

I'm trying to run an expo react native app, and I'm getting that error. I have given full access to disk to terminal and vs code on Mac. I have also tried using sudo. Please help.

[image of terminal commands used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkKoY.png)

I tried using sudo and given full disk access to terminal and vs code but it's not working.